# Is this code remotely correct while saving data into array in JSON format using Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one 'CRUD' application using Angular4 and here user can create,read,update and delete the data. Those inserted data are saved into array value in JSON format. I am explaining some of my code below.

```
if (articles.length != 0) 
           { 
                let maxIndex = articles.length - 1;
                let articleWithMaxIndex = articles[maxIndex];
                let articleId = articleWithMaxIndex.id + 1;
                article.id = articleId;
           }
           else
           {
                article.id = 1;
           }
```

Here I am generating the `id` for for each `article` submission. Here I need to know Is this the correct way to generate the `dynamic id` for each article while this code is going to production because there is also `delete article` functionality implemented here.

Comment: Impossible to tell. Where is this data being stored? Are there potentially multiple users creating data?

Comment: In addition, it would depend on whether the articles array is sorted on the Id and not some more user-friendly field such as the article title.

Comment: Can't you use a UUID instead of manually generating the id?

Comment: In most large apps that I've worked on, the id assignment is handled in the database when the row is saved and *not* handled in the client code.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen : Data is stored into a json file inside that project folder.

Comment: @DeborahK  : But here I am not using any database. Just storing the data into one json file.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot insert, update, or delete from a local json file in the project folder. You can only read the values. (Unless you are using some type of in-memory web API?)

Comment: I had just one doubt as delete option is here. Lets say user deleted the `5th index` record again while creating the record the creating id will be `5` but using in sql type database its started from next value `i.e-6`.

Comment: @Menaka : Is there any angular4 `UUID` package ?

Comment: Check this out. I'm not completely sure whether it's angular4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-uuid

Comment: @Menaka : Its for angular.js1 and there should like [`https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-uuid).